# Other than SessionPool interface, how to create aligned time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am still learning how to use Apache IoTDB, and I am corresponding the official guide with the actual practice. Seems like there is no interface for creating aligned time series in "SessionPool". I wonder do the aligned time series only can be created with "Session" interface?

I am still new to the system, so I checked the official guide, but seems like it is not clear for this question. Wonder if anyone can answer my question so I can understand the guidance better.